# QGIS - cutting a shape with multiple non-contiguous lines

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation

I'm trying to cut a shape in QGIS with a set of lines that don't form a single continuous path - they define an edge without holes, but they overlap each other rather than terminating at exactly the start of the next line. I cannot figure out how to use these to cut a polygon - even if I merge the lines, the polygon isn't cut.

Below is a (bad) basic depiction of what I want. Note that the two lines are separate (though in the same multiline layer), and neither extends across the entire width of the polygon.

[image: A bad basic diagram of what I want]

How can I accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run Menu Processing / Toolbox / [Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) with the line layer twice as Input layer **and** as Split layer. Like this, the lines get split at the point where they intersect.
2. Select the two features that form the line you want to use for splitting the polygon (highlighted in yellow in the screenshot) and merge them - delete the other two small lines (red, the dangles).
3. Now again run [Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines), this time with the polygon as input layer and the rectified line as split layer.

[image]

**Edit**

[See also here for a solution to the problem of the invalid line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/416609/88814).

The line you provided in the comments has invalid geometries. Repair it to be able to use if for splitting. Convert from [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts). Then extend the single lines using `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geometry by expression` with the expression `extend( $geometry,1,1)`. Then use the resulting layer with the initial solution above.

Another (manual) solution is to convert the line from Multipart to singleparts, then manually snap the vertices of conncting start- and end-segments together. Like this, splitting becomes possible:

*Activate snapping and use the vertex tool to move the end-vetex of one line to the start-vertex of the next line:*
[image]

Comment: This looks like the right answer, but step 3 doesn't seem to be doing anything. The input polygon is output unchanged. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your data? Maybe the polygon contains geometry errors?

Comment: Sure - the data is North American countries in this data set: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-countries/. The line I have goes from Mexico to Canada, and none of Mexico, the US, or Canada will split along it

Comment: Actually Mexico will split; the line wasn't quite outside the border. Is there a possibility that a merged line might have gaps?

Comment: Providing just the polygons does not help much: you should also provide the line you want to use to split. Otherwise, I don't have any idea how it looks and where it goes.

Comment: That's fair. What's a good way to do that?

Comment: Upload it to a cloud (sharing platform) and share the link here.

Comment: Try this https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6zbsjwbzsc49in2/AACc1pdGX78opzz9pnKAgCWha?dl=0

Comment: The file you provided is not a valid data source

Comment: I'm rather new to GIS things and don't have the first idea what might be the problem or the solution. What would be the proper way to export just a line from QGIS?

Comment: EXport/save it as Geopackage - then you get just one file

Comment: Try the .gpkg file in this dropbox folder - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6zbsjwbzsc49in2/AACc1pdGX78opzz9pnKAgCWha?dl=0

Comment: You line is not a clean line and contains errors. You should repair it or re-draw a simple, clean line.

Comment: The only practical way to recreate the line is to do exactly what I did to create it - copy/paste segments from various sources and merge them. The line needs to have the exact shape it has. What can I do to repair it? A quick Google search isn't returning anything useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131512/discussion-between-sjiveru-and-babel).

Comment: "Copy/paste segments from various sources and merge them" indeed results in a very messy geometry. There is no way then to clean it up. Did you try the steps from the updated answer? Doing it manually for the line you provided is not so cumbersome, there are about 6 spots where you have to snap the vertices.

Comment: I did try the steps, and went and manually snapped the vertices, and it still wouldn't merge the line there. Am I maybe using the wrong merge tool?